# JUnit 5 multiple parametrized tests with same parameters - migrate Parameterized

Tags: java, testing, junit, migration, junit5

Previously in JUnit4 you could do something like this:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyTest
{
    private final int number;

    public MyTest(int number) {
        this.play = play;
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsEven() {
        assertEquals(true, number % 2 == 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsNotOdd() {
        assertEquals(false, number % 2 != 0);
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static int[] data() {
        return new int[] { 2, 4, 6 } 
    }
}
```

This would go trough the array, instantiate `MyTest` with each of the values and then run all of the tests on each of those instances. See the [Parameterized docs](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) for more details.

Now in JUnit5 things have changed, according to the [new docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests) you'd have to write the same tests like this:

```
public class MyTest {
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("data")
    public void testIsEven(int number) {
        assertEquals(true, number % 2 == 0);
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("data")
    public void testIsNotOdd(int number) {
        assertEquals(false, number % 2 != 0);
    }

    public static int[] data() {
        return new int[] { 2, 4, 6 } 
    }
}
```

You have to repeat the parameter and the data source for each individual test. Is there a way to do something similar as in JUnit4, where the parameterized tests work on instances of the class instantiated with the different parameters?

Comment: There is an open issue for this: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/878

Comment: This is likely the better issue to watch: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/871

Comment: @RolandWeisleder, perhaps you'd like to make our comments an answer. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

(a summary of the comments)

Reusing the same parameters for all/multiple methods in a test class is currently (version 5.3.2 and 5.4.0-M1) not supported. But this is already a request the JUnit team is working on, see

- [Introduce extension API for container templates (#871)](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/871)
- [Allow @ParameterizedTest declarations at type level for TCKs (#878)](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/878)

Answer (score 1):

As of today (JUnit 5.3.2 or 5.4.0-M1) it seems not.

I tried to create an `Extension` to handle such a case, but test class instantiation happens before `TestTemplateInvocationContextProvider` extensions are taken into account.

So it seems not possible to have multiple instantiation contexts for a same test class.

You surely may ask the core team about this by opening an issue on the [JUnit5 github repository](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5).

Comment: As previously mentioned in comments, there already exists an issue in JUnit 5's issue tracker: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/871

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR junit5 supports meta annotations. You can define a custom annotation and put it on your tests instead:

```
@MethodSource("data")
@ParameterizedTest
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface OldParameterizedTest {
}

public class MyTest {
    @OldParameterizedTest
    public void testIsEven(int number) {
        assertEquals(true, number % 2 == 0);
    }

    public static int[] data() {
        return new int[] { 2, 4, 6 } 
    }
}
```